# Filter data and copy information to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of codes in B18 up to col AC.

Rows 13,15 and 17 are always blank and are a part of the heading.

```
      B C   D   E   F   G   H
12  Codes   Desc    AP  TP  CP  DP  LP
13                          
14          TEP Q1  PR1 Q1 LT   LR1    
15                          
16  ABC xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx    
17                              
18  ab3 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
19  ab4 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
20  ab5 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
21  bd2 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
22  bd3 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
23  bd4 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
24  bd4 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
25  bd6 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
26  bd7 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
27  bd7 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
28  bd9 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
```

In a separate codes sheet, I have a list of codes for look up

```
Codes
ab3
bd4
```

I want to filter on the codes above and the result on a new sheet:

```
    B   C   D   E   F   G
1   Codes   Desc    AP  TP  CP  DP  
2                           
3           TEP Q1  PR1 Q1 LT   LR1
4                           
5   ABC xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
6                           
7   ab3 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
8   bd4 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
9   bd4 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to show us an example of what you're trying to accomplish. Right now I don't understand at all.

Comment: Sorry about this again. But I wanted to include a tabular format as in excel sheet but the formatting has gone flat again.

Comment: Still quite cryptic. Are you just trying to copy to a new sheet the rows whose value in the A column match one of those in your "filter" list? Should the whole row be copied, or just columns A:AC? Also, please format as `code` to get fixed-width font, and align columns properly, otherwise it's a pain to read.

Comment: I am so sorry about the format. This is the best I could get to. Values in col A are hidden and I dont really need them. I need all header rows from B12 to AC17 to be copied across on to a new sheet alongwith the filtered data. So I want the macro to look up for the codes in the codes sheet and filter/find all data for these codes in the original sheet and copy and paste on a new sheet alongwith the hearders from B12 to AC17. Hope its clearer than before.

Comment: so to rephrase your question: you want to make an extract from sheet A into a new sheet N. You want to select rows according to a criterium in column [B] of sheet A. All codes you are interested in are listed in a code sheet C

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. Rename the sheets and redefine the ranges as appropriate.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRowsThatHaveTheRightCode()

    ' Assuming:
    ' Sheet1 is source sheet
    ' Sheet3 is destination sheet
    ' Codes are placed in Sheet2, starting at A2.

    Dim iSourceRow As Long
    Dim iDestinationRow As Long
    Dim iCode As Long
    Dim varCodes As Variant
    Dim booCopyThisRow As Boolean

    ' Copy headers (assuming you want this)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B12:AC16").Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B12:AC16")

    ' Get the pass codes
    varCodes = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Resize(2, 1)
    ' Or wherever your codes are.

    ' Loop through all rows in source sheet
    iDestinationRow = 0
    For iSourceRow = 1 To 11 ' or however many rows you have
        booCopyThisRow = False
        For iCode = LBound(varCodes, 1) To UBound(varCodes, 1)
            If varCodes(iCode, 1) _
                = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B18").Cells(iSourceRow, 1) Then
                ' Code matches.
                booCopyThisRow = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next iCode
        If booCopyThisRow = True Then
            ' Copy into next available destination row.
            iDestinationRow = iDestinationRow + 1
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B18").Cells(iSourceRow, 1).Resize(1, 28).Copy _
                Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B18").Cells(iDestinationRow, 1)
        End If
    Next iSourceRow


End Sub
```